# Appending Python Threads to list

Tags: python, multithreading, join

I am trying to append Threads to a list in Python for the purpose of iterating over them with the join method later. However when I append the Thread object to a list it creates two entries in the list. One for the Thread and one following it for a function object. 
The relevant code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import errno
import sys
import operator
import threading
import time

def removeDuplicates(oldList):
    newList = list();

    for i in oldList:
        if i not in newList:
            newList.append(i)

    return newList;

def expandRange(portRange):
   if "-" not in portRange:
       l = list()
       l.append(int(portRange))
       return l

   portLimits=portRange.split("-")
   return range(int(portLimits[0]),int(portLimits[1])+1)

def parsePorts(portList):
    if "," in portList:
        ports = portList.split(",")
        portRanges = [expandRange(i) for i in ports]
        portRanges = reduce(operator.add, portRanges)
        ports = removeDuplicates(portRanges)
        return ports
        else:
            l = list()
            l.append(int(portList))
#            print "I AM HERE" ,l
            return l


def check_port(host, port):
    try:
        activeThreads.append(id);
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host,port))

        mutex.acquire()
        print "%s:%s ---> Port open!" %  (host,port)
        mutex.release()

    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
            mutex.acquire()
            print "%s:%s ---> Port closed" %  (host,port)
            mutex.release()
            s.close()
        elif e.errno == errno.ETIMEDOUT:
            mutex.acquire()
            print "%s:%s ---> Connection timed out" %  (host,port)
            mutex.release()
            s.close()
        elif e.errno == errno.ENOEXEC:
            mutex.acquire()
            print "%s:%s ---> Host down" %  (host,port)
            mutex.release()
            s.close()
        else:
            raise



if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Usage is:\n %s <host> <port>" % sys.argv[0]
    exit(1)


host = sys.argv[1]
portList = sys.argv[2]
ports = parsePorts(portList);
activeThreads = list()
#print activeThreads
mutex = threading.Lock()
print "Thread objects: "


for port in ports:
   try:
       newThread = threading.Thread(target=check_port,args=(host,port))
       print type(newThread)
       activeThreads.append(newThread)
       newThread.start()
#       print " THREADS: %s" % activeThreads
   except:
      raise
      #print "Error: unable to start thread"



print "\nActiveThreads list:"
#print activeThreads
counter = 0;
for t in activeThreads: 
#    print "[%d] => %s" % (counter,type(t))
    print counter, t, type(t)
    counter+=1;

time.sleep(5)
```

The resulting output is the following:

```
Thread objects:
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>
<class 'threading.Thread'>

ActiveThreads list:
0 <Thread(Thread-1, started -2146345816)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
1 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
2 <Thread(Thread-2, started -2146342704)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
3 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
4 <Thread(Thread-3, started -2146339968)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
5 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
6 <Thread(Thread-4, started -2146337288)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
7 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
8 <Thread(Thread-5, started -2146334528)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
9 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
10 <Thread(Thread-6, started -2146330960)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
11 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
12 <Thread(Thread-7, started -2146328288)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
13 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
14 <Thread(Thread-8, started -2146325480)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
15 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
16 <Thread(Thread-9, started -2146322832)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
17 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
18 <Thread(Thread-10, started -2146320160)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
19 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
20 <Thread(Thread-11, started -2146317512)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
21 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
22 <Thread(Thread-12, started -2146314760)> <class 'threading.Thread'>
23 <built-in function id> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
localhost:25 ---> Port closed
localhost:113 ---> Port closed
localhost:32 ---> Port closed
localhost:110 ---> Port closed
localhost:81 ---> Port closed
localhost:112 ---> Port closed
localhost:33 ---> Port closed
localhost:82 ---> Port closed
localhost:80 ---> Port closed
localhost:34 ---> Port closed
localhost:111 ---> Port closed
localhost:90 ---> Port closed
```

What are these resulting builtin_function_or_methods that are being appended to the list along with the thread objects? How do I just get a list of threads to iterate and call .join() on?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just do `print counter, t, type(t)` in the loop? By the way instead of using a manual counter, use `enumerate`.

Comment: code looks fine, please show `parsePorts` and `check_port` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks fine. Thanks for adding the missing methods.

You should remove `activeThreads.append(id);` in your `check_port` method, because `id` is a [builtin-function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) of python and the missing brackets give a `builtin_function_or_method` type error.

After that a join of all threads is easy:

```
for t in activeThreads: 
    t.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize id was a builtin function! Code works great now. Much appreciated!